# Поиск элемента на странице (Firebug)

Tags: html, javascript, firebug, css

Есть *HTML*-код, который генерируется автоматически. И вот, стала задача, допустим, найти быстро элемент с атрибутом `class=begin`.

Подскажите, как раскрыть данный элемент?

Что-то наподобие стрелки в *Firebug* "показать элемент", но он сейчас скрыт и я не вижу его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В firebug есть поиск по HTML-тексту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это то, что вы искали?

Comment: судя по описано оно.Помогите найти .Где эта пиктограмма находится?

Comment: @zloctb  http://upyourpic.org/images/201310/qkffga4z22.png

Comment: Благодарен за помощь.